# Do I need to rewrite my Project for the webservice because of database connectivity?

Tags: java, web-services, database-connection, tomcat8

I added to a project a Webservice. The webservice needs gets a string and passes it to a function of the project and shall return the answer string.

The string shall be saved the database. When I run the Project in the console all works fine but, but when I run the webservice on Tomcat I get following Error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@VM-PROJ-852:1521:xe
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.brain.io.datasource.DataSourceDB.con(DataSourceDB.java:28)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.brain.io.datasource.DataSourceDB.selectstatement(DataSourceDB.java:44)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.brain.io.datasource.DataSourceDB.readAll(DataSourceDB.java:100)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.brain.ModelChatbotBrain.init(ModelChatbotBrain.java:31)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.BotInit.init(BotInit.java:38)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.BotInit.<init>(BotInit.java:33)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.ws.WSTEST.<init>(WSTEST.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.makeNewServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:385)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getNewServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:235)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:91)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:287)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 18, 2015 6:25:44 AM org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet processAxisFault
INFORMATION: AxisFault:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.lang.NullPointerException
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.brain.io.datasource.DataSourceDB.readAll(DataSourceDB.java:105)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.brain.ModelChatbotBrain.init(ModelChatbotBrain.java:31)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.BotInit.init(BotInit.java:38)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.BotInit.&lt;init&gt;(BotInit.java:33)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.ws.WSTEST.&lt;init&gt;(WSTEST.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.makeNewServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:385)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getNewServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:235)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:91)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:287)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:VM-PROJ-852
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}isRuntimeException:true

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:333)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.brain.io.datasource.DataSourceDB.readAll(DataSourceDB.java:105)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.brain.ModelChatbotBrain.init(ModelChatbotBrain.java:31)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.BotInit.init(BotInit.java:38)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.model.BotInit.<init>(BotInit.java:33)
    at de.morpheus.chatbot.ws.WSTEST.<init>(WSTEST.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.makeNewServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:385)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getNewServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:235)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceObject(JavaProvider.java:91)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:287)
    ... 31 more
```

Here is the code in the project I used to connect to the database

```
public Connection con()
{
    String host1 ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@VM-PROJ-852:1521:xe";
    String username ="Steve";
    String password = "sys";
    Connection con = null;
    try{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection( host1, username, password );
    return con;
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        return con;
    }
}
```

I dont know how and what to change. I hope you guys can help.

Comment: It looks as if it's looking for an ojdbc driver. do you have ojdbc6.jar in your project? on your web service? or does your tomcat have ojdbc6.jar on your/tomcat/directory/bin?

Comment: Here's a useful link on how to establish that connection - http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U didnt define driver type use this "

### oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

" as driver

add this statement at beginning of ur code

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you have the correct oracle driver is in the class path and then add the following code

```
static{
    try {
        Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```